# How to set a specific field to not null?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have a table where two columns show the country and the passport respectively both being type varchar, it also have other columns but are not relevant for the problem, and I want to add a constraint where a specific country may not have a passport. For example, only the country Italy can have a passport or can be set as null and the other countries must have a passport.

I have tried this code:

```
alter table profesor alter column passport set not null where country != 'Italy'
```

Which drops the next error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "where" 
LINE 1: ...able profesor alter column passport set not null where country... 
                                                             ^ 
SQL state: 42601 
Character: 58
```

Comment: What could possibly be the intention of this code?  A column cannot be "occasionally" `NOT NULL`.  It either is or isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a `check` constraint, not a `not null` constraint:

```
alter table profesor
    add constraint chk_profesor_passport
        check (passport is not null or country = 'Italy');
```

Comment: can you help me with other question please? My table have a column that show the phone number and I want to add a constraint where this number must be in a specific format like +cod.country-cod.local-num.local. For example: +54-351-4350114.

And later I want to add a constraint where num.local must have at least 7 digits.

Comment: @aristi95 . . . New questions should be asked as *questions* and not in comments.

Comment: yes sorry it is just that I have to wait 90 minutes. But thank you anyways.

Comment: @aristi95: Be aware that this still allows `insert into profesor(passport, country) VALUES (NULL, NULL);` as CHECK constraints only prevent rows where the expression evaluates to `FALSE`.